# Tkinter no funciona-Python 3.5

Tags: python

Estoy intentando hacer un GUI con Python 3.5, pero me da un error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\Python\GUI_test.py", line 2, in 
>       class Application(Frame):
>     File "C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\Python\GUI_test.py", line 13, in Application
>       root = Tkinter.Tk()
>   NameError: name 'Tkinter' is not defined

Aqui el script:

```
from tkinter import *
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.myButton = Button(self, text='Button Label')
        self.myButton.grid()

    root = Tkinter.Tk()

    root.title('Frame w/ Button')
    root.geometry('200x200')

    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Como puedo solucionar esto?

Answer (score 7):

En Python 3.x el módulo `Tkinter` (como se llamaba en `Python 2.x`) pasó a llamarse `tkinter`. Lo importas bien pero al instanciarlo dejas la `t` en mayúscula por lo que el intérprete no sabe a que módulo haces referencia. Además, usas `from modulo import*` por lo que importas Tk directamente, el prefijo no es necesario:

```
 root = Tkinter.Tk()
```

por:

```
 root = Tk()
```

No obstante, usar wildcard (`*`) para importar es una mala práctica por varias razones excepto en un puñado de casos muy concretos. La forma común de importar correctamente tkinter es mediante el alias `tk`:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
```

La forma que inicialmente usabas también sería apropiada, pero te obliga a escribir algo más:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
```

importar solo los nombres que uses también sería aceptable:

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
```

Por otro lado, instancias tu clase `Application` dentro de la misma clase (puede que solo sea un error al formatear tu código en la pregunta), esto te dará otro error.

Por último el método `mainloop()` lo debes usar sobre la aplicación (`app`) no sobre la ventana (`root`) que es un `Frame`. El código debería ser:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.myButton = tk.Button(self, text='Button Label')
        self.myButton.grid()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Frame w/ Button')
root.geometry('200x200')

app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```